# excel unique value: Find rows which doesn't have a corresponding match

Tags: excel

I'm having a little trouble getting my desired results on Excel. Ive tried using the conditional formatting but it's not displaying the values which doesn't have match.

Example:

```
    C1    C2
R1    10    
R2    10    
R3    10    
R4    10    
R5        10
R6        10
R7        20
```

[image: !]

When using the standard conditional formatting in Excel to find unique values, it will only highight R7 because the value "20" doesn't have a match in Column 1.

What I'm looking for is to highlight Row 3, 4 and 7 because Rows 3 and 4 doesn't have any remaining match in Column 2 and Row 7 doesn't have any match in Column 1.

Is this possible?

Comment: Wouldn't row 3 also be highlighted?

Comment: Missed that one. You're right Scott! I'm looking for a way to highlight values in Column 1 which doesn't have any remaining match in Column 2. Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For column A:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,A1)>COUNTIF($B:$B,A1)
```

For Column B the inverse

```
=COUNTIF($B$1:$B1,B1)>COUNTIF($A:$A,B1)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, thank you so much for your help. I'll try this on my actual data. have a good day!